# How to run java program in linux terminal using classpath

Tags: java, mysql, linux, terminal, classpath

i am new to linux terminal and does not know how to run java file using classpath.

```
  class Test{
      public static void main(String[] args){
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
                System.err.println("Couldn't find driver class!");
            }
      }
    }
```

The program compiled but unable to run.I have "mysql.jar" in the same directory. But i am unable to run this file. How can i run this file using classpath

Comment: try `java -cp ./:mysql.jar Test`

Comment: I have added my comment as answer. Feel free to upvote/accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
java -cp ./:mysql.jar Test
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is "ClassNotFound"?
You must include all the class files your application needs

```
java -classpath mysql.jar:. Test
```